# Sabre flight search - BFM

Tags: sabre

I am looking for search implementation where I can get multiple cabin type fares for each itenary of one specific airline. My request  search parameters would be origin, destination, date, pax count with pax types.

Comment: So what have your tried so far? What is your problem? And are you using BFM Soap or Rest? It is possible to do that with BFM!

Comment: I am using BFM REST service for this. Objective to achieve is all cabin type fares for all itineraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bargain Finder Max the Multiple Fares Per Itinerary feature allows you to in quickly offer multiple fare choices per itinerary in a single query to best match their needs.

The Multiple Fare Per Itinerary feature is applicable to Bargain Finder Max only. You can create up to 10 user defined groups with up to 6 associated fare attributes per group. This feature is applicable to one-way, round-trip, and multi-destination itinerary requests.

***Extract for the API documentation***

**Fare Attributes**

All Multiple Fares Per Itinerary fare attributes are optional. A mix of attributes per group is allowed, using “AND” for different attributes and “OR” for same attributes.

Following are accepted fare attributes:

- Fares without restrictions.
- Exclude fares with advance purchase.
- Exclude fares with penalty.
- Exclude fares with min/max stay.
- Passenger Type Code – If a passenger type is not specified, the “ADT” -passenger type code will be used as the default passenger type code.Only one passenger type code is allowed per group.
- Cabin.Only one cabin is allowed per group. If the requested cabin is not offered, no fare will be returned
- Account ID/Corporate ID.
- Public Fare.
- Private Fare.

Multiple Fares Per Itinerary will use the specified total number of passengers in the existing qualifier for each parameter group in the shopping request. The user will not enter the number of passengers in the Multiple Fares Per Itinerary request.

Comment: I am using BFM REST service. Do you have code sample for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been working on just this, and it's working great. - here's a sample of the JSON that should return Economy, Prem. Economny and Business Class for each itinerary (where available).

Insert inside: OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ > TravelPreferences > TPA_Extensions

```
"FlexibleFares": {
  "FareParameters": [
    {
      "PassengerType": {
        "Code": "ADT"
      },
      "Cabin": {
        "Type": "Y"
      }
    },
    {
      "PassengerType": {
        "Code": "ADT"
      },
      "Cabin": {
        "Type": "S"
      }
    },
    {
      "PassengerType": {
        "Code": "ADT"
      },
      "Cabin": {
        "Type": "C"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```